# Recording IP Camera stream with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, ip-camera

Hey I am trying to record the **IP camera stream** using **FFMPEG** . But it is giving me Input/Output error .
Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -i http://admin:@ip:81/livestream.cgi E:\Video\my.h264
```

My camera is H264 encoded. Now Please help how to remove this error .
Any Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am saving my content using this and its working fine. Check if the input is correct or try to put the specifics of the video while receiving the stream.

```bash
ffmpeg -i http://admin:admin@192.2.2.1:554/dd-a -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "outfile.mp4"
```

Comment: basically the input URL of my camera liverstreaming is this:
http://169.254.128.10:81/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename=
what should be its respected ffmpeg command to store it to output file. Any Help Please

Comment: aint the above command with your URL not working? i guess it should work directly. The username/password should work directly. If possible, if you can create the URL without the username/password, or try to capture the traffic with wireshark while running the ffmpeg request and you will be able to see what is the causingthe issue

Answer (score 4):

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://ownaddress/live.sdp -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 900 -segment_atclocktime 1 out%03d.mp4
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but explaining how it works would be beneficial.