# FFMPEG IP Camera Stream Recording

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, ip-camera

What is the short command for storing this input stream into some external file ?

```
http://10.11.16.10:81/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename=
```

This is the input stream. Now I want to save it in new.mp4||.flv
What would be the **FFMPEG** command ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recording IP Camera stream with FFMPEG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454833/recording-ip-camera-stream-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i "http://169.254.128.10:81/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename=" -c:v libx264 -an output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `ffmpeg -i http://10.11.16.10:81/livestream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=&streamid=0&audio=0&filename= recording.mp4` should work. The `-i` option denotes the input url and the second parameter is the output file. If you need remuxing or transcoding then other options will be needed.