# ffmpeg IP camera unable to record

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am using an Amcrest POE camera. I have assigned it a static IP which I am able to confirm by logging into it via the browser. Its IP is 192.168.1.200.

I tried following the instructions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454833/recording-ip-camera-stream-with-ffmpeg) but couldn't get it to work. I get:

```
http://admin:admin@192.168.1.200/dd-a End of file
```

The official ffmpeg documentation does not talk about -segment_time or -segment_format. What is the ffmepg command to grab a stream for a fixed duration and write it to an .mp4 file?

Answer (score -1):

This got it working:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.200 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

Though I still am figuring out how to get a fixed duration dump.