# How to optimize file size of recorded camera stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc

I am recording stream from camera using different approaches. I tried to record camera stream using ffmpeg. I looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464175/5128696 and used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://user:password@192.168.0.101/video.cgi?resolution=vga -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "outfile%03d.mp4"
```

It worked, but file size peaked at **45Mb for 2 minutes video.**

Then I used VLC to record stream. Result file for fragment of same length was **about 2Mb**

How do I optimize the recorded file size? My camera gives 640x480 video stream without audio, and 45Mb is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. Remove this option to re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -i http://user:password@192.168.0.101/video.cgi?resolution=vga -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 "outfile%03d.mp4"
```

This will use the default settings for the encoder named libx264. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more options.

Comment: using this command I obtained 2 min 45 sec video with 1800Kb approximately, so it worked. My camera gives picture of 640x480, so the file is small.